# Sql injections may be possible

Tags: php, sql, yii, sql-injection

I am using zaproxy tool for auto testing the app

I am getting the `SQL injection may be possible` issue:

It is hitting the save url with title `" ZAP-Story 11Th Feb-01 AND 1=1 --"`

I am using yii. Please help me out in getting rid of this issue.

Comment: without providing any source code, we can't have a look at your source code to check where the problem may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to ans your query without source code, but still try this:

Try binding parameters which you pass in query instead of directly passing in it.
for example:

$query = UserMaster::model()->findAll('email = :email  ', array(':email' => "rk@gmail.com"));

Here email id is binded in an array, this will prevent sql injection to much extent.